# How do I set the app bar to be under the status bar at the top of the page?

Tags: flutter

I am wanting to make my AppBar go to the top of the page and just be visible under the bar that displays the time and battery level etc.. how would I go about doing this?

[What I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wUJh.png)

I'd like to reduce what I currently have to just be under the status bar ^^

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: Please, provide code for your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your `Scaffold` with a [`SafeArea`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html) Widget. This will prevent the `Scaffold` and with this also the `AppBar` from overlapping the status bar (which is part of the safe area):

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: Center(
            child: Text('Foo'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```